# Complexity Computation

Tags: time-complexity

i have to analyse this code's complexity but i'm very comfused with the **condition** of **IF**.

```
sum=0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
  for(j=1;j<i*i; j++){
      if(j%i==0){
         for(k=0;k<j;k++){
          sum++;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If the **"(j%i==0)"** if-condition was not there i would be able to compute the complexity but i cant understand it. I need some explanation about how we can compute how many times this condition will be true.

Thank you.

Comment: For a give i and j, the condition will be true j/i times. Is that enough of a hint?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the algorithm would be O(n^3), because of the 3 for statements.

You can have a look at [if statement - how does IF affect complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917958/how-does-if-affect-complexity)

where there is a nice link on more information.