# time complexity of recursion function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I don't know where to start to calculate the time complexity of this function. What is O(time complexity) of this function? I learned that the answer is 3^n.

```
int f3(int n) {
    if (n < 100)
        return 1;
    return n* f3(n-1) * f3(n-2) * f3(n-3)
}
```

Comment: For starters, it has a different time complexity depending on whether `n >= 100` or not.  Manually run through the code for `n=103` and extrapolate.  Also, this will overflow `int` pretty quickly.

Comment: This has been answed before just need to look at it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917958/how-does-if-affect-complexity)

Comment: I think that we should calculate it from n to 103.  After 103 it is not important to look at the others but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Start by writing down the recurrence relation for the complexity.

Comment: Why all the three languages?

Comment: @AditiRawat because adding TurboC++ would have been a gauche overreach.

Comment: Recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467674/determining-complexity-for-recursive-functions-big-o-notation

Comment: If you develop the call tree you will easily see that for any great $n$ the tree has degree 3 and that every path from the root to a leave has length of order $n$.

Comment: I am amazed that WHY SO members down vote this question !!! It is so similar to [this question:today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836794/time-complexity-of-the-code-containing-condition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have: 

 1 : if statement

 3 : * operator

 3 : function statement

 Totally: 7

So we have:

```
T(n)=t(n-1) + t(n-2) + t(n-3) + 7
T(99)=1
T(98)=1
...
T(1)=1
```

Then to **reduce** `T(n)`, we have `T(n-3)<T(n-2)<T(n-1)`   therefore:

```
T(n) <= T(n-1)+T(n-1)+T(n-1) + 7
T(n) <= 3T(n-1) + 7
```

So we can solve `T(n) = 3T(n-1) + 7` (in big numbers `T(n-1)` is almost equal `T(n-2)` and ... )

Then we can calculate `T(n)` by following approach:

```
T(n) = 3.T(n-1) + 7
     =3.(3.T(n-2)+7) + 7     = 3^2.T(n-2) + 7.(3^1 + 3^0)
     =3^2.(3.T(n-3)+7) + ... = 3^3.T(n-3) + 7.(3^2 + 3^1 + 3^0)
                             = 3^4.T(n-4) + 7.(3^4 + 3^2 + 3^1 + 3^0)
     ...
     =3^(n-99).T(n-(n-99)) + 7.(3^(n-98) + 3^(n-97) + ...+ 3^1 + 3^0)
     =3^(n-99) + 7.(3^(n-98) + 3^(n-97) + ...+ 3^1 + 3^0)
```

So consider that `1 + 3 + 3^2 ...+3^(n-1) = 3^n - 1/2`

Therefore we reached:

```
T(n) = 3^(n-99) + 7.(3^(n-99) + 1/2) = 8.3^(n-99) - 7/2
     = 8/(3^99) . 3^n -7/2
```

**Finally**: Big O is `O(3^n)`

If you just have `T(1)=1`, the answer is the same.